# Can't pass custom text to Facebook Wall Post - Android API

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to allow the users of my app to publish stories on their walls from my application for things such as Achievements(for example) within my application. Here is the activity code, adapted from the HelloFacebookActivitySample:

With both activities, I can see my app name, description, and link no problem when I post. Using the latest version of the FB SDK. However, the string (message) that I pass through the newStatusUpdateRequest() method is not displayed.

(In this attempt, I'm trying to pass text from a text view)
The first way I tried it:

```
public class Settings_Facebook extends FragmentActivity {

    //Constants
    private static final String PERMISSION = "publish_actions";
    private final String PENDING_ACTION_BUNDLE_KEY = "com.facebook.MyApp:PendingAction";
    //Views
    private Button postStatusUpdateButton;
    private Button postPhotoButton;
    private LoginButton loginButton;
    private ProfilePictureView profilePictureView;
    private TextView greeting;
    //Variables
    private PendingAction pendingAction = PendingAction.NONE;
    private ViewGroup controlsContainer;
    private GraphUser user;
    private GraphPlace place;
    private List<GraphUser> tags;
    private boolean canPresentShareDialog;
    private enum PendingAction {
        NONE,
        POST_PHOTO,
        POST_STATUS_UPDATE
    }
    private UiLifecycleHelper uiHelper;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        uiHelper = new UiLifecycleHelper(this, callback);
        uiHelper.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            String name = savedInstanceState.getString(PENDING_ACTION_BUNDLE_KEY);
            pendingAction = PendingAction.valueOf(name);
        }

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings__facebook);

        loginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.login_button);
        loginButton.setUserInfoChangedCallback(new LoginButton.UserInfoChangedCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onUserInfoFetched(GraphUser user) {
                Settings_Facebook.this.user = user;
                updateUI();
                // It's possible that we were waiting for this.user to be populated in order to post a
                // status update.
                handlePendingAction();
            }
        });

        profilePictureView = (ProfilePictureView) findViewById(R.id.profilePicture);
        greeting = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.greeting);

        postStatusUpdateButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.postStatusUpdateButton);
        postStatusUpdateButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                onClickPostStatusUpdate();
            }
        });

        postPhotoButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.postPhotoButton);
        postPhotoButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                onClickPostPhoto();
            }
        });

        controlsContainer = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.main_ui_container);

        canPresentShareDialog = FacebookDialog.canPresentShareDialog(this,
                FacebookDialog.ShareDialogFeature.SHARE_DIALOG);
    }


    private Session.StatusCallback callback = new Session.StatusCallback() {
        @Override
        public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
            onSessionStateChange(session, state, exception);
        }
    };

    private FacebookDialog.Callback dialogCallback = new FacebookDialog.Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookDialog.PendingCall pendingCall, Exception error, Bundle data) {
            Log.d("HelloFacebook", String.format("Error: %s", error.toString()));
        }

        @Override
        public void onComplete(FacebookDialog.PendingCall pendingCall, Bundle data) {
            Log.d("HelloFacebook", "Success!");
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        uiHelper.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putString(PENDING_ACTION_BUNDLE_KEY, pendingAction.name());
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        uiHelper.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data, dialogCallback);
    }

    private void onSessionStateChange(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
        if (pendingAction != PendingAction.NONE &&
                (exception instanceof FacebookOperationCanceledException ||
                exception instanceof FacebookAuthorizationException)) {
                new AlertDialog.Builder(Settings_Facebook.this)
                    .setTitle(R.string.cancelled)
                    .setMessage(R.string.permission_not_granted)
                    .setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, null)
                    .show();
            pendingAction = PendingAction.NONE;
        } else if (state == SessionState.OPENED_TOKEN_UPDATED) {
            handlePendingAction();
        }
        updateUI();
    }

    private void updateUI() {
        Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
        boolean enableButtons = (session != null && session.isOpened());

        postStatusUpdateButton.setEnabled(enableButtons || canPresentShareDialog);
        postPhotoButton.setEnabled(enableButtons);

        if (enableButtons && user != null) {
            profilePictureView.setProfileId(user.getId());
            greeting.setText(getString(R.string.hello_user, user.getFirstName()));
        } else {
            profilePictureView.setProfileId(null);
            greeting.setText(null);
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("incomplete-switch")
    private void handlePendingAction() {
        PendingAction previouslyPendingAction = pendingAction;
        // These actions may re-set pendingAction if they are still pending, but we assume they
        // will succeed.
        pendingAction = PendingAction.NONE;

        switch (previouslyPendingAction) {
            case POST_PHOTO:
                postPhoto();
                break;
            case POST_STATUS_UPDATE:
                postStatusUpdate();
                break;
        }
    }

    private interface GraphObjectWithId extends GraphObject {
        String getId();
    }

    private void showPublishResult(String message, GraphObject result, FacebookRequestError error) {
        String title = null;
        String alertMessage = null;
        if (error == null) {
            title = getString(R.string.success);
            String id = result.cast(GraphObjectWithId.class).getId();
            alertMessage = getString(R.string.successfully_posted_post, message, id);
        } else {
            title = getString(R.string.error);
            alertMessage = error.getErrorMessage();
        }

        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setTitle(title)
                .setMessage(alertMessage)
                .setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, null)
                .show();
    }

    private void onClickPostStatusUpdate() {
        performPublish(PendingAction.POST_STATUS_UPDATE, canPresentShareDialog);
    }

    private FacebookDialog.ShareDialogBuilder createShareDialogBuilder() {
        return new FacebookDialog.ShareDialogBuilder(this)
                .setName("MyApplication")
                .setDescription("The description of the app")
                .setLink("https://play.google.com/store/");
    }

    private void postStatusUpdate() {
        final EditText simpleEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editStatus);
        final String message = simpleEditText.getText().toString();

        Bundle postParams = new Bundle();
        postParams.putString("name", "Facebook SDK for Android");
        postParams.putString("caption", "Build great social apps and get more installs.");
        postParams.putString("description", "The Facebook SDK for Android makes it easier and faster to develop Facebook integrated Android apps.");
        postParams.putString("link", "https://developers.facebook.com/android");
        postParams.putString("picture", "https://raw.github.com/fbsamples/ios-3.x-howtos/master/Images/iossdk_logo.png");

        if (canPresentShareDialog) {
            FacebookDialog shareDialog = createShareDialogBuilder().build();
            uiHelper.trackPendingDialogCall(shareDialog.present());
        } 
        else if (user != null && hasPublishPermission()) {
            Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
            Request request = new Request(session,"me/feed",postParams,HttpMethod.POST);

            RequestAsyncTask task = new RequestAsyncTask(request);
            task.execute();
//                    .newStatusUpdateRequest(Session.getActiveSession(), message, place, tags, new Request.Callback() {
//                        @Override
//                        public void onCompleted(Response response) {
//                            showPublishResult(message, response.getGraphObject(), response.getError());
//                        }
//                    });
//            request.executeAsync();
        } 
        else {
            pendingAction = PendingAction.POST_STATUS_UPDATE;
        }
    }

    private void onClickPostPhoto() {
        performPublish(PendingAction.POST_PHOTO, false);
    }

    private void postPhoto() {
        if (hasPublishPermission()) {
            Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.drawable.button_focus);
            Request request = Request.newUploadPhotoRequest(Session.getActiveSession(), image, new Request.Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                    showPublishResult(getString(R.string.photo_post), response.getGraphObject(), response.getError());
                }
            });
            request.executeAsync();
        } else {
            pendingAction = PendingAction.POST_PHOTO;
        }
    }

    private boolean hasPublishPermission() {
        Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
        return session != null && session.getPermissions().contains("publish_actions");
    }

    private void performPublish(PendingAction action, boolean allowNoSession) {
        Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
        if (session != null) {
            pendingAction = action;
            if (hasPublishPermission()) {
                // We can do the action right away.
                handlePendingAction();
                return;
            } else if (session.isOpened()) {
                // We need to get new permissions, then complete the action when we get called back.
                session.requestNewPublishPermissions(new Session.NewPermissionsRequest(this, PERMISSION));
                return;
            }
        }

        if (allowNoSession) {
            pendingAction = action;
            handlePendingAction();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        uiHelper.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        uiHelper.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        uiHelper.onResume();
        updateUI();
    }
}
```

(in this attempt I'm passing a bundle of parameters)
The second way I tried it(Just the postStatusUpdate() method was changed):

```
 private void postStatusUpdate() {
        final EditText simpleEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editStatus);
        final String message = simpleEditText.getText().toString();

        Bundle postParams = new Bundle();
        postParams.putString("name", "Facebook SDK for Android");
        postParams.putString("caption", "Build great social apps and get more installs.");
        postParams.putString("description", "The Facebook SDK for Android makes it easier and faster to develop Facebook integrated Android apps.");
        postParams.putString("link", "https://developers.facebook.com/android");
        postParams.putString("picture", "https://raw.github.com/fbsamples/ios-3.x-howtos/master/Images/iossdk_logo.png");

        if (canPresentShareDialog) {
            FacebookDialog shareDialog = createShareDialogBuilder().build();
            uiHelper.trackPendingDialogCall(shareDialog.present());
        } 
        else if (user != null && hasPublishPermission()) {
            Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
            Request request = new Request(session,"me/feed",postParams,HttpMethod.POST);

            RequestAsyncTask task = new RequestAsyncTask(request);
            task.execute();
        } 
        else {
            pendingAction = PendingAction.POST_STATUS_UPDATE;
        }
    }
```

Comment: "I'd like for them to be able to post without having to type in the post content" - careful with that, the posted message always has to be 100% user generated, see facebook terms. so, at some point, the user will have to create the message.

Comment: What about things like achievements, for example? I'll update the description because you've got a point there.

Comment: there´s a separate api for achievements: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/achievements/

Comment: Hmm... I will look into that. The only issue there, however, is that its only available to apps categorized as games. This application is a health a wellness app that unlocks various user achievements for not smoking.

Comment: funny, i wanted do develop a non-smoker app with achievements some years ago, but i was too lazy...lol...anyway, i would use open graph for this, it´s perfect. i will put up an answer with the links you need :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For achievements, you can either use the Achievements API or Open Graph Actions/Objects. Since the Achievements are only available for games, Open Graph Actions are the way to go. Here are some links to get you started:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/getting-started/
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/using-actions/

Keep in mind that it may take some hours or even some days until the Open Graph Actions are accepted by Facebook.

You can also publish Open Graph Actions in the background without user confirmation, as long as the user can change the publishing in a settings dialog, for example.

Comment: Thanks Luschn! I was looking at the API and though this was the direction I would need to take.